# How to make Xcode always remember your session or sign in automatically on start?

Tags: apple-id, xcode, ide

Every time I close Xcode and then start it, I have to enter my AppleID and password. I have to go

`Preferences > Accounts` and provide my password every time. This is very annoying.

How to force it to remember my session or sign in automatically.

```
System:
    OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
    CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Memory: 2.39 GB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4819257
    Emacs: 22.1.1 - /usr/bin/emacs
    Nano: 2.0.6 - /usr/bin/nano
    Sublime Text: Build 3176
    Vim: 8.0 - /usr/bin/vim
    VSCode: 1.25.0 - /usr/local/bin/code
    Xcode: 9.4.1/9F2000 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
```